# Input 5 names and pair each with a unique item from list randomly

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website atm and its mostly CMS but we can add a html segment with code. I want to build something whit what you can input 5 names and after pressing a button it matches every name with a word from a given list, so the output is 5 pairings and nothing should double. For example paiting the letters a-e with the numbers 1-5 and i want a random list of pairings (a1,b3,c4,d2,e5/a2,b1,c3,d5,e4... etc.) but no letter or number can appear twice in the same line. So you input 5 names and press a button do get a random listt of pairings, is something like that possible and if it is, how do i do this.

Thanks in advance.

A newbie looking for guidance

Comment: You click the button and you get exactly ONE output (5 items, e.g. `a1,b3,c4,d2,e5`)? Are the lists (letters, numbers) always the same size?

Comment: Yes exactly one output and the two list will be limited to five items each, for clearance i want to assign each person to for example a task, but the tasks should have exactly ONE person doing them every task must be featured in the output line.

Comment: like where do I put the function you wrote for the randomizer. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const otherList = [
  `task 1`,
  `task 2`,
  `task 3`,
  `task 4`,
  `taxk 5`,
];

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const names = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].map(x => x.value);
  const tasks = shuffleArray(otherList);
  
  $('output').html(
    names.map((n, idx) => `${n} => ${tasks[idx]}`).join('<br />')
  );
});

function shuffleArray(inputArray) {
  const array = [...inputArray];
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 1" required value="Example 1" /> <br />
  <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 2" required value="Example 2" /> <br />
  <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 3" required value="Example 3" /> <br />
  <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 4" required value="Example 4" /> <br />
  <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name 5" required value="Example 5" /> <br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
  <br /><br />
</form>

<output></output>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but what do i hjave to do do implement it on my website, the script is pairing the input with the pre given items, but what do i have to do to get it running on my website? I just have a simple field where i can input the html code.

Comment: You need to be able to run HTML and JavaScript. You can embed scripts via `<script>` tags as long as your software allows it. Just like your website this example above is just running embedded HTML and JavaScript on this page -- same concept.

Comment: So there is a tab where i can input java script, would that be the one? and to i paste it in a doc and save it as exmp.js ? Because atm i Just see the input and the go button but i dont get an output, even if i paste your script into the java script part.

Comment: Edit: Where can i review the js output, is there a possibility to print it via html so there is something like a box under the go button, where it puts the line of output, because i want it to be displayed on the website and not in the console

Comment: Sure. Anything is possible once you have the mapping. I've updated the answer to show output below the form.